# Cassandra Setup and Use In Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, cassandra

I am facing a problem when I'm trying to use Git Bash to ant build.

Before that I would like to show my Environment Variable.

1) Extract Cassandra folder into D:/Program Files (x86)/Cassandra-trunk

2) Extract apache-ant-1.9.1 into D:/Program Files (x86)/Cassandra-trunk

After that I run Git Bash and input the command as below.

*$cd D:/'Program Files (x86)'/Cassandra-trunk/apache-ant-1.9.1/bin*

*$ ant build*

The error message:

*Buildfile: build.xml does not exist.*

*Build failed.*

I used to put build.xml into the /bin but error too.

Is there any method I can fix this problem?

Reference:

http://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/RunningCassandraInEclipse

http://uisurumadushanka89.blogspot.com/2012/02/apache-cassandra-how-to-setup-source.html

Answer (score 0):

After you have cloned cassandra source code into cassandra-trunk you will find build.xml file into cassandra-trunk folder. So instead of:

```
$cd D:/'Program Files (x86)'/Cassandra-trunk/apache-ant-1.9.1/bin
```

you should do:

```
$cd D:/'Program Files (x86)'/Cassandra-trunk/
```

This is where build.xml file resides. Now run `ant build` from above directory. Please make sure that you have included ant folder into your environment build path variable otherwise you would not be able to run ant executable directly from cassandra-trunk folder.

I hope this helps.